# Simple laser projector for terminal screen

Tags: projector, laser

I'm looking for a tiny, cheap laser projector that just outputs texts from a terminal. That's it. The simpler, the better. The output can be low resolution pixels or laser traced lines.

Like the laser part of a [laser projection keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnoTC.jpg).

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for requiring a laser projector? Any requirements for resolution? If laser, you could either use a projector that displays pixels or traces the paths of characters; Any preference there?

Comment: @Romen No preference, but a laser that traces the path is better suited for the task.

Comment: 1) What's the measured ambient lighting where you wish to use the device? There's an app for that: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+app+measure+light+level 2) Do you have full spectrum colour vision (not everyone does, ya know)?